# Ajax web service call not working in chrome browser

Tags: web-services, ajax, ecb-menu

Can any point me to the error am doing in this block of code. This is working fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox but not in Chrome.
Chrome does not return the result.

```
   function CallListWS_PublishedLib(m, ctx) {

 var ReviseStatus;
 var isHyperLink;

  if(ctx.listTemplate == 10055)
    {
   var soapEnv =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> \
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>" + ctx.listName + "</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Revise' /> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Is_x0020_HyperLink_x003F_' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                    <query> \
                        <Query><Where> \
                            <Eq> \
                                <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                                <Value Type='Integer'>" + currentItemID + "</Value> \
                            </Eq> \
                        </Where></Query>\
                    </query> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";


     var wsurl = ctx.HttpRoot + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
     var strAction="STSNavigate('"+ctx.HttpRoot + "/_layouts/IHIS.MOSS.SGH.Solution/ReviseDocument.aspx?" + "ID=" + currentItemID + "&List=" + ctx.listName +"')";




    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: wsurl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: function(xData, status) {
             ReviseStatus = $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row:eq(0)").attr("ows_Revise");
             isHyperLink = $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row:eq(0)").attr("ows_Is_x0020_HyperLink_x003F_");

        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
    }

    alert(ReviseStatus);
    alert(isHyperLink);


    return [ReviseStatus, isHyperLink];
}
```

Comment: add 'error: function(response, status, error) { console.log(status + "-" + error) }' to your list of ajax options.  This will give you a little better idea of whats happening.  Then change 'complete:' to 'success:'.  Complete fires either way and you only want to run to run your code if it actually works.

Comment: Also, what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SharePoint are you in? 2010? 2007?  Also, is chrome giving you any kind of error when you look at the call through the debugging tools.  Check the console and the network tools to see if the call is going through. There are several options available for SharePoint web services so you do not have to create the soap packages yourself.  In 2007/ 2010 you can use [spservices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) for SharePoint.  The guy who made that library is a awesome and a real expert in the SharePoint world.  In 2010 you can use the JavaScript object model for SharePoint or REST for SharePoint.  Examples can be found [here](http://scottcurrier.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/rest-and-sharepoint-2010-quick-start-guide-sample-browser-client-with-jquery/).  If you need more examples let me know.

Comment: thanks i was able to see the response of webservice through the chrome developer tools. The problem was with cross browser functionality. found the problem as noted in the below link http://maxmorrow.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/jquery-caml-query-lists-asmx-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the xml response as detailed below link.
http://maxmorrow.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/jquery-caml-query-lists-asmx-web-service/

i changed the below lines and worked fine in chrome and firefox.

InternalStatus = $(xData.responseXML).find("z\:row:eq(0),row:eq(0)").attr("ows_Internal_x0020_Status");
             isHyperLink = $(xData.responseXML).find("z\:row:eq(0),row:eq(0)").attr("ows_Is_x0020_HyperLink_x003F_");